# SQL: Selecting columns from most recent child table entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, greatest-n-per-group

I'm currently trying to find a way to retrieve all records in a table with their most recent associated child record. A simplified table structure would look as follows:

```
Parents        Children
______         ________
Id             Id
Age            ParentId 
               FirstName
               LastName
               DateCreated
```

I'm looking to get all parents with the first and last name of their most recently created child (ordered by `DateCreated`). These tables are very large in practice and I'm hoping to gain some performance over selecting all parents and all their associated children which is what I currently have via the following query:

```
select * from parents p join children c on p.id = c.parentid
```

and then finding the desired results with application code in memory.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with a subquery:

```
select p.*, c.firstname, c.lastname
from parents p
inner join children c on c.parentid = p.id
where c.datecreated = (
    select max(c1.datecreated)
    from children c1
    where c1.parentid = c.parentid
) c
```

Another option is a lateral join:

```
select p.*, c.firstname, c.lastname
from parents p
cross apply (
    select top (1) c.*
    from children c
    where c.parentid = p.id
    order by c.datecreated desc
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use a lateral join (i.e. `apply`):

```
select p.*, c.*
from parents p cross apply
     (select top (1) c.*
      from children c 
      where p.id = c.parentid
      order by c.datecreated desc
     ) c;
```

For optimal performance, you want an index on `children(parentid, datecreated desc)`.